# Exporting data to Excel in MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, excel, model-view-controller

I am looking at various methods of exporting data to Excel in my MVC application.

1. A lot of the libraries require the data to be stored in DataTables.
2. I have my data passed into a model to access from a View. It seems that you cannot pass this model back to a controller.
3. JavaScript is an option if it's not exported as html table but a pure Excel file.

Currently, I'm calling a function that will run the queries again to build a string and use System.IO.File.WriteAllText that will output the file. I don't prefer this way as I have to call the database to run the queries again (I already have all the data I need in a model in the View) and the path is hardcoded, I'd like a Save Dialog to pop up.

Is there a better way of doing this?

I would really like one of the two ways below:

1. Find a "trick" to pass the data from the View back to the controller, maybe TempData can be used in the View somehow?
2. JavaScript that will produce a pure Excel (.xlsx) file

   ```
   List<type> record = GetRecords();

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   sb.AppendLine("Data 1, Data 2, Data 3, Data 4");

   foreach (var item in record)
   {
      sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}\n", item.1, item.2, item.3, item.4);
   }

   System.IO.File.WriteAllText("myfile.csv", sb.ToString());
   ```

Comment: js-xlsx (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)  is javascript library that can produce a pure xlsx file. Would that help you?

Comment: I ended up going with the below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample). Excel files can be created entirely in XML. The format is OpenXML. By itself it's not much fun to work with, but this library makes it manageable. You can build the XML file on demand and then stream it in the response, so from the user's perspective they're downloading an Excel file. The linked page shows how to start from a data source (in this case a DataTable), create the spreadsheet, and add it to an HttpResponse. You can create worksheets with formulas and even workbooks with multiple worksheets.

Comment: If you want to edit that data in Excel and continue posting it back to the server, that's something that you'll need to manage in Excel. It wouldn't be easy. You'd need code executing in the spreadsheet that would post back to the server as edits were made. You wouldn't want the server to respond with more Excel because then you'd have a whole new spreadsheet to download each time. You could have them edit the spreadsheet and post the whole file back and then parse it. But I think it would be easier just to do it in the browser.